# Faster alternatives to cv::imread when decoding into GPU memory?

Tags: c++, opencv

My pipeline begins by either consuming an image from disk, or an encoded image in CPU memory. I need to ultimately end up with a decoded RGB / BGR buffer in GPU memory, ideally in a `cv::cuda::GpuMat` object.

As of right now, if the image is on disk, I call `cv::imread()` and then `cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload()`. If the encoded image is already in CPU memory, then I call `cv::imdecode()` and then `cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload()`.

To me, this seems very inefficient because the decoding is done using the CPU, whereas I imagine it would be much faster to do so using the GPU. Latency is fairly critical for my use case.

Are there any alternatives to the above using OpenCV methods that would be faster? I can't seem to locate a `cv::cuda::imread()` or `cv::cuda::imdecode()` method. Any idea why these don't exist? Is the only alternative to use something like `nvjpeg` for example?

**Edit**
I'm mainly working with JPG and PNG images.

Comment: Is there a mistake in your question? "If the encoded image is already in CPU memory, then I call cv::cuda::imdecode() and" vs. "I can't seem to locate a  cv::cuda::imdecode() method." which one is right?

Comment: What is your total SSD bandwidth and CPU?

Comment: @Micka yes there was a type, thanks for pointing it out. I've fixed it.

Comment: The key parameter for performance is the image format. Some format require (nearly) no decoding time like BMP, but they take a lot of disk space and disk/memory/PCI throughput and this can be the bottleneck. Formats like JPEG can be computed on the GPU though this is not the most efficient one. The good point is that JPEG files are small. PNG files cannot be efficiently decoded on the GPU. There are many other format. Some of them are specifically designed for GPU computation. Do you have constraints on the input format? This is not mentioned in the question. Please add it.

Comment: opencv's cuda stuff interoperates with native cuda calls. you can probably use "nvJPEG" -- @talonmies please justify why you believe this isn't related to CUDA. it clearly looks like a CUDA question.

Comment: crosspost (including answer): https://forum.opencv.org/t/why-is-there-no-cuda-accelerated-image-encoding-decoding-methods/14287

Comment: This is OpenCV performance question. The `cv::cuda` namespace doesn’t make it a CUDA related programming question. It has nothing to do with any sort of concrete CUDA programming question or the direct use of any of the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit  core APIs.  By extension, if this question *is* a CUDA question,  then so are 1000s of other OpenCV questions, plus 100000 Tensorflow and Pytorch questions, and a lots of other. At which point 5 out of 6 “CUDA” questions are not related to CUDA programming, and the core knowledge base of CUDA programming here is diluted beyond usefulness.That’s why

Comment: clearly OP is asking how to decode JPEGs through CUDA. you seem to categorically reject all CUDA questions that involve opencv. I think that is illogical. your argument to the "1000s of other" questions is weak. yes, these questions may have CUDA at the heart of the issue. the amount of questions doesn't matter. -- you should edit the usage guidelines of the CUDA tag to be as narrow as you want. be prepared for debate. how about you take this discussion to Meta? you seem to be very invested.